# moniter the Python function

Tags: python

I want do something after some function exec in Python, but I cannot change or call the function. have some idea?

for example:

```
class Target(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.__id = 123

  def fun(self):
    print "called by target %d" % self.__id
```

I want print something after "fun" run, but I cannot change or call class Target

Comment: I feel you must rephrase your question.

Comment: So you want `fun` to behave different without directly changing `Target`? Make a subclass that inherits from `Target` and override `fun`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's fine for you to just replace the original method with a wrapper method:

```
t = Target()

old_fun = t.fun
def new_fun():
    old_fun()
    print "even more fun"

t.fun = new_fun
t.fun()
```

prints:

> called by target 123
>   even more fun

Note that this will not change the class, but only the instance.

Comment: Though it *is* possible to do the same thing for all instances of `Target` if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTarget(Target):
    def fun(self):
        super(MyTarget, self).fun()
        # your custom post processing
```

**EDIT:** Since controlling object creation isn't an option, you might consider using a variation of Mr. Steak's answer. If you want the post processing to affect all instances of `Target`, you can use something like the following:

```
Target.old_fun = Target.fun
def new_fun(self):
    self.old_fun()
    # custom post-processing
Target.fun = new_fun
```

Comment: That's assuming you can get the system to use your subclass in lieu of `Target`

Comment: hi, jpm! I afraid I explain unclearly. I cannot change class and I also cannot extend class. because some class create instance of class, and call function.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue. In that case, a variation of Mr. Steak's answer might be a good bet.

Comment: @wenz Can you access the instance after it was created but before the function is called?